# Given a point (x,y,z) and an angle/bearing distance calculate the end point (x,y,z) in python

Tags: python, geometry, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I am trying to figure how to correctly code this. Imagine a camera is on a gimble against a 10 ft high drone.  Old vector: {'X': 39.375346, 'Y': 10.0, 'Z': -84.208137} new vector: (30.130935697561846, 4.0, -71.61683531351122)

I feel this is wildly inaccurate on my part, I'm looking to improve this. Do I need to do some unit conversion to get a better answer?

#python example.

```
#code by adam dabdoub


import math 
import numpy

x = 39.375346
y = 10.0
z = -84.208137
V1 = {'X': x, 'Y': y, 'Z': z}
G1 = math.degrees(45) #degrees
A1 = math.degrees(45) # or 45 degrees
R = 10 #radius to target or distance to target

#180 degrees = west
#90 degrees = south
#270 degrees = north
#0 degrees = east

a = y
c = a//(math.cos(a))
b = math.sqrt(c ** 2 + a ** 2)
x1 = (b * math.cos(A1) + x)
y1 = ((y - y) + 4)
z1 = (b * math.sin(A1) + z) 
V2 = (x1,y1,z1)
print("UAV Coordinates:\n", V1)
print("Person Coordinates:\n", V2)
```

Comment: What do you mean by old vector and new vector?

Comment: Problem instance: - An Rc airplane equiped with a GIMBAL camera is at V1 or vector one. with g1 or gimbal angle and A1 be azimuth/direction (N,S,E,W). A person in the field is v2 or vector 2. Assume the gimbal angle directly points at the person or v2. if given V1(x,y,z),r, A1, G1, please find the location of the person or v2(x1,y1,z1). V1=(39.375346,10, -84.208137) G1=45 degrees A1= 3.14/4 or 45 degrees R= 10 radius to target or distance to target 180 degrees = west 90 degrees = south 270 degrees = north0 0 degrees = east